# Using the "watch" field in "description" in JSON editor

Tags: javascript, html, json, jsoneditor

I'm using a JSON configuration schema which gets pushed to a website which should by using this [JSON editor](https://github.com/json-editor/json-editor). And I would like to have the user input shown in the description field. Here is a snippet of the JSON file:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "file_name"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "file_name": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "<h3>Table name</h3>",
      "description": "Only alphanumeric characters dash and underscores are allowed.</br>Your data will be loaded to some_path.{your table name}",
      "options": {
        "inputAttributes": {
              "placeholder": "your table name"
        }
      },
      "propertyOrder": 100
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to have the "Table name" inputted by the user in the "description" field instead of {your table name}. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/json-editor/json-editor) you can use the "watch" variable:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "first_name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "last_name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "full_name": {
      "type": "string",
      "template": "{{fname}} {{lname}}",
      "watch": {
        "fname": "first_name",
        "lname": "last_name"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this doesn't work in the "description" field. Any ideas how I can deal with this?